# Google Chart y AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-visualization

Tengo una pequeña inquietud, actualmente requiero generar estadisticas de registros por fechas del año:

**CONSULTA MYSQL**

```
SELECT fecha_registro AS Fecha,
count(*) AS Registros
FROM persona
WHERE id_tipoUsuario = '4'
AND  empresa_per = '$id_empresa'
GROUP BY MONTH(Fecha)
```

**RESULTADO**

La consulta responde a lo esperado, que es obtener los registros realizados durante el mes correspondiente.

**RESULTADO CONSULTA**

[image: MySql]

**FUNCIÓN ANGULARJS**

```
  $scope.importarEstadisticas = function()
{
  $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'mainApp/Estadisticas/estadisticaMeses.php'
    })
    .then(function successCallback(datosEstadisicasMeses)
    {
      $scope.tableEstadisticas = datosEstadisicasMeses.data;

    },function errorCallback(datosEstadisicasMeses)
    {
      console.log("Error, al tratar de traer los datos")
    });
}
$scope.importarEstadisticas();
```

**RESULTADO FUNCIÓN**

[image: AngularJS]

**GOOGLE CHART**

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mes', 'Registros'],
    ['Enero',  214],
    ['Febrero',  789],
    ['Marzo',  894],
    ['Abril',  1030]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Gráfica de Visitantes',
    hAxis: {title: 'Meses',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'Black'}},
    vAxis: {minValue: 0}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Aquí es donde radica mi problema, porque requiero pasarle los datos obtenidos de mi consulta al array de GoogleChart. Derivado en sus dos filas, Fecha y Registros. En vez de Mes sería la fecha obtenida, y en vez de los valores dados manualmente sería el conteo obtenido de la consuolta.

Gracias!

**formatoGrafica**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muestranos el valor de `$scope.tableEstadisticas = datosEstadisicasMeses.data;`

Comment: disculpa, creí que habia subido las imagenes, ahora puedes echar un vistaso el valor que retorna. El valor de la consulta es de produccion, el de la funcion es un valor que se retorna en local Gracias! @sioesi,

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es recorrer el arreglo que tienes de respuesta.

La estructura que recibes del servicio que consumes son objetos con Fecha y Registro, por lo tanto :

Para obtener las cabeceras Fecha y Registro

```
var cabeceras = Object.keys($scope.tableEstadisticas[0]); //Aqui se obtiene los valores Fecha y Registros, para las cabeceras de tu grafico.
var formatoGrafico = [];
formatoGrafico.push(cabeceras); //Se dejan como primer elemento en el arreglo Formato.
$scope.tableEstadisticas.forEach(function(registro, index) {
    //Se recorren los datos y se cargan al arreglo con el mismo formato.
    formatoGrafico.push([registro.Fecha, registro.Registros]);
});

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([formatoGrafico]);
```

Comment: me da como respuesta **Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string** en la vista.

Comment: puedes mostrarme que te imprime formatoGrafico? creo que me falto `[]`

Comment: claro, puedes visualizarlo.

Comment: probaste con los corchetes? no deberia fallar...

Comment: Si, ya lo probé y el error persiste.

Comment: por eso te dije, puedes copiar en esta conversacion el resultado de formatoGrafico? imprimirlo?

Comment: Esto es lo que imprime dentro el 

`console.log("Formato: ", formatoGrafico)`



`(3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0
:
(2) ["Fecha", "Registros"]
1
:
(2) ["2017-11-29", "1"]
2
:
(2) ["2017-12-01", "6"]
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Realmente, pienso igual, debería de funcionar, porque tiene la misma estructura dada para el `arrayToDataTable`, cuando solo eran valores predefinidos en el `Array`

Comment: @jecorrales perfcto, actualizare mi respuesta!

Comment: si sabes el por que del error? que pena molestar, pero, me urge, gracias!

Comment: @jecorrales el error es por el formato que acepta el grafico, hay que modificar eso, pero no tuve tiempo de modificar mi respuesta, apenas pueda te ayudo con eso!, en todo caso estamos super cerca :D, solo hay que modificarlo

Comment: jajaj excelente, estoy a la espera, gracias!

Comment: Bro, ayudame jajaj que aun no he podido con eso... gracias @sioesi

Comment: me puedes ayudar por favor?

Comment: @jecorrales puedes crear un codepen o algo asi para ver el codigo mejor y funcionando?